# How to validate dtypes columns and get name column if not is correct dtype?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to validate each column dtype by first assigning their respective dtype that I want for each column.

I'm trying with this data that I read from a csv.

```
In[1]:import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd
      
In[2]: d = {'ID': [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, np.nan], 'NAME': ['KWI', 'NED', 'RICK', 'NICH', 'DIONIC', 'RICHARD', 'ROCKY', 'CARLOS', 'SIDARTH%', ' '], 'ID_COUNTRY':[1, 2, 3,4/,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'COUNTRY':['MEXICO', 'ITALY', 'CANADA#', 'ENGLAND', 'GERMANY', 'UNITED STATES', 'JAPAN', 'SPAIN', 'BRAZIL', ''], 'ID_CITY':[10!, 20, 21, 31, 18, 27, 36, 86, 28, np.nan], 'CITY':['MX', 'IT', 'CA', 'ENG', 'GE', 'US', 'JP', 'SP', 'BZ', np.nan], 'STATUS': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK','']}
      df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
      #df here is show it to get in context but I read it with 
      #df=pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', encoding='utf8', sep=',')
      df
Out[3]: df:
      ID        NAME      ID_COUNTRY     COUNTRY          ID_CITY       CITY     STATUS
0     14.0       KWI           1           MEXICO           10!          MX        OK
1     14.0       NED           2           ITALY            20.0         IT        OK
2     14.0       RICK          3           CANADA#          21.0         CA        OK
3     14.0       NICH          4/          ENGLAND          31.0         ENG       OK
4     14.0       DIONIC        5           GERMANY          18.0         GE        OK 
5     14.0       RICHARD       6           UNITED STATES    27.0         US        NOT
6     14.0       ROCKY         7           JAPAN            36.0         JP        OK
7     14.0       CARLOS        8           SPAIN            86.0         SP        NOT
8     14.0       SIDHART%      9           BRAZIL           28.0         BZ        OK
9     NaN                     10                            NaN         NaN
```

The dtypes from the csv are:

```
ID            float64
NAME           object
ID_COUNTRY     object
COUNTRY        object
ID_CITY        object
CITY           object
STATUS         object
dtype: object
```

What I need is to after separate columns by name or position as:

```
a=df.iloc[:,[0,2,4]]
b=df.iloc[:,[1,3,5,6]]
```

Set `dtypes` as `a.astype("Int64")` and `b.astype("str")` but how you can see in some columns this conversion can't be done, so for that reason I need to get the column name that can be converted to the desired `dtype`.
For example:

```
ID_COUNTRY has invalid data.
ID_CITY has invalid data.
```

Or if there any invalid `string` that can be converted also show it, but in this case isn´t the case because I believe that almost everything can be converted to `string dtype`.

The idea I have is maybe try with `for loops` by iterating column by column and if there is a value data in any column that can't be converted to the desired `dtype` promt out the name column that have that error.

Comment: That `d = {...}` line raises a syntax error on the 4/ and there is also a ! in there. Did this come from a CSV file?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It comes from a csv but I wanted to show the data for explanation.

Comment: But that's the thing. Its not valid python and so I can't build a df that looks like yours. I can "fix" those problems manually and then `a.astype("int64")` fails with `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer` while `a.astype("Int64")` works. The thing is, you haven't given us the dtypes of `a` or a way to initialize a df like yours, so I'm kinda stuck on a solution.

Comment: If you have some bad data in the csv and the column with "4/" is a string, you could use a regex with .replace to fix it before making it an int64. Depending on whether you want to keep the nan values, you could `a.fillna(0).astype("int64")` ... if its reasonable to change nan to zero.

Comment: Ok. I will added @tdelaney

Comment: No, for this reason I can't change or replace anything it is necessary to promt out an Error if there is any column name can not be converted to the desired dtype @tdelaney

Comment: Maybe using for loops iterating column by column? @tdelaney

Comment: If its supposed to break, then you're already there!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. Your cannot set column dtype due to invalid data as you said.

For `a.astype("Int64")`, the last row has `Nan`, it cannot convert to `int64` type.
My suggestion is that you drop this row, or accept `float` as the dtype.

If you go with the first solution:

```
a.dropna().astype('int')
```

Ps. there are some typo in the code of `ID_COUNTRY`.

Comment: I desagree with your comment because it is proved that it does not matter if there is a `NaN` if you want to convert to Integer. You can try it if you remove `/` and `!` from the columns and then set `a.astype("Int64")`.

Comment: Hi MetalJacket, I have removed the `/` and `!` in my experiment. It turns out there are still errors when convert `Nan` to `int`. You could try this: `pd.DataFrame([1, float('nan')]).astype('int')`. It pops error: `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Comment: That's weird. I just remove the errors and apply `df.iloc[:,[0,2,4]].astype("Int64)"` and they converted to Int64. The nans appear as <NaN> but in dtypes appear Int64.

Comment: Em... It's really weird. I just tried it again. And `df.iloc[:,[0,2,4]].astype("Int64)"` still pops error `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`... Maybe it related to pandas version? Mine is `'0.23.4'`

Comment: Sorry it is: df.iloc[:,[0,2,4]].astype("Int64"). I have the version 1.1.1. Maybe is that. @Patrick Lee